# extract gene names multiple times from fasta header in r

Tags: r, header

Hi I want to extract the gene names from a faster headers multiple times, or as many times as it appears in the header. An example of faster header is

```
tr|Q22501|Q22501_CAEEL 3-phosphoadenosine-5-phosphosulfate synthase OS=Caenorhabditis elegans OX=6239 GN=pps-1 PE=1 SV=1;tr|A0A061AE05|A0A061AE05_CAEEL 3-phosphoadenosine-5-phosphosulfate synthase OS=Caenorhabditis elegans OX=6239 GN=pps-1 PE=1 SV=1
```

I want to extract 'GN=pps-1' twice from this faster header, or as many as 'GN=' appears in the faster header.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a file `foo.fasta` with the content:

```
>tr|Q22501|Q22501_CAEEL 3-phosphoadenosine-5-phosphosulfate synthase OS=Caenorhabditis elegans OX=6239 GN=pps-1 PE=1 SV=1
ATGATGAT
>tr|A0A061AE05|A0A061AE05_CAEEL 3-phosphoadenosine-5-phosphosulfate synthase OS=Caenorhabditis elegans OX=6239 GN=pps-1 PE=1 SV=1
ATATATA
```

Then you can use this to get a table of attributes with columns header, name, and value:

```
library(tidyverse)

"foo.fasta"  %>%
  read_lines() %>%
  keep(~ .x %>% str_detect("^>")) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  rename(header = value) %>%
  mutate(
    attributes = header %>% map(~ {
      .x %>%
        str_split(" ") %>%
        simplify() %>%
        keep(~ .x %>% str_detect("="))
    })
  ) %>%
  unnest(attributes) %>%
  separate(col = attributes, into = c("name", "value"), sep = "=")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I'm trying to go through all the pipes, which is quite complicated to me.